# Windows 7 netcat error: 'nc' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cmd

This is what's happening:

```
C:\Windows\system32>nc -v 10.1.2.205 22
'nc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Below is my screenshot:

[image]

Kindly help me on this issue.

Comment: Please include relevant code/commands and the error message in the question. Don't add them as comment, edit the post.

Comment: just call NC with it's path, e.g. `c:\temp\nc -v 10.1.2.205 22`, using the correct path to nc instead of c:\temp.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- download NetCat from here https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/
- unzip it and put is somewhere (eg: in C:)
- use directly in the command prompt like: **c:\netcat-1.11\nc google.com 80**
- optional: add to Environment Variables to be used from any context
  [image: NetCat]

Or install Nmap (includes Netcat)

- for Windows https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-7.30-setup.exe
- for Mac https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-7.30.dmg

To check whether ncat is installed and working, open up two terminals. In one of them, run **ncat -l 9999** then in the other, **ncat localhost 9999**. Then type something into each terminal and press Enter. You should see the message on the opposite terminal.
Look in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=qeQ6pKxUp-Q

Comment: Hi Dan, I apologize for delay in accepting your solution.

Answer (score 2):

- Download netcat 1.12 from https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/
- Extract the files (e.g. C:\NetCat)
- Open two cmd prompts and navigated to `cd \NetCat`.
- Execute `nc.exe -l -p 9999` in one cmd window and `nc.exe localhost 9999` in another. Note that I'm on a 32b windows7, for 64bit use nc64.exe.
- Test by typing `Hello` in one command window and check if it is displayed in the other.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the path to nc.exe to your PATH environment variable.
Here's a walkthrough if you dunno how to acheive this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28545224/5119765

Answer (score 1):

- Download **NMap** from https://nmap.org/download.html and install it
- Select **Environment Variables** under **System Properties**
- Select **PATH**
- Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\` at the end